# Does not trigger the Web API from Angular 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, angular5

I have attached my Component.ts, service.TS, AND in Web Api. Can you help me to get data from SP. I am using MVC .
This is my component.ts

```
GetComponentListForGrid() {this._componentservice.getAllComponentList(this.compartid_auto,this.progid,this.ComponentId,this.ComponentDescription,this.ComponentType,
        this.ComponentMake,this.EquipModel).subscribe(result => {
          console.log('GetAvailableCompartsAll', result);
          this._componentList.push(...result);
      }, error => { }, () => { this._loading.startLoading(); });
    }
```

This is Service.ts

```
public getAllComponentList(compartid_auto :string, progid :string,ComponentId :string,ComponentDescription:string,ComponentType:string,ComponentMake :string,EquipModel:string): Observable<ComponentList[]> {
        let options = {
          params: new HttpParams().set('compartid_auto', compartid_auto).set('progid', progid)
          .set('ComponentId', ComponentId).set('ComponentDescription', ComponentDescription)
          .set('ComponentType', ComponentType).set('ComponentMake', ComponentMake)
          .set('EquipModel', EquipModel)
        };
        return this._http.get("api/Component/getComponents", options).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
      }
```

this is my Web API

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(List<Component_Details>))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetComponents(int module, string compID, string compDesc, string compType, string equipMake, string equipModel, string compMake, string compSize)
        {
            Component_Details c = new Component_Details();
            List<Component_Details> compList = new List<Component_Details>();
            DataTable dt = Component.getCompartmentList(module, compID, compDesc, compType, equipMake, equipModel, compMake, 0);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                c.compartid_auto = dr["compartid_auto"].ToString();
                c.progid = dr["progid"].ToString();
                c.ComponentId = dr["CompID"].ToString();
                c.ComponentDescription = dr["CompDesc"].ToString();
                c.ComponentType = dr["CompType"].ToString();
                if (dr.ItemArray.Length > 5)
                    c.ComponentMake = dr["CompMake"].ToString();
                else
                    c.ComponentMake = string.Empty;
                if (dr.ItemArray.Length > 6)
                    c.EquipModel = dr["EquipModel"].ToString();
                else
                    c.EquipModel = string.Empty;

                compList.Add(c);
            }
             return Ok(compList);
        }
```

I fetch data from Stored Procedure

```
public static DataTable getCompartmentList(int module, string compID, string compDesc, string compType, string equipMake, string equipModel, string compMake, int compSize)
        {
            string cnnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TTDALConnection"].ConnectionString;
            DataTable dt = null;
            try
            {
                SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("store_procedure_name", cnn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "spGetCompartmentsList";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@progid", module));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compId", compID));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compDesc", compDesc));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compType", compType));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@equipMake", equipMake));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@equipModel", equipModel));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compMake", compMake));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compSize", compSize));
                cnn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(dr);
                return dt;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Comment: your WebApi controller expects a `Post` yet you use `Get` on your angular service

Comment: yeah. I have use in my Controller. I have attached that code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you are performing an http GET but your api method is configured to use HttpPost

```
this._http.get("api/Component/getComponents", options).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

The second issue is that you are sending the the parameters as querystring. 
When doing a POST, the recommended way is to send the data in the request body.
Therefore, try it this way.

Create a model and post it from the client

```
public getAllComponentList(compartid_auto :string, progid :string,ComponentId :string,ComponentDescription:string,ComponentType:string,ComponentMake :string,EquipModel:string): Observable<ComponentList[]> {
        let options = {
          params: new HttpParams().set('compartid_auto', compartid_auto).set('progid', progid)
          .set('ComponentId', ComponentId).set('ComponentDescription', ComponentDescription)
          .set('ComponentType', ComponentType).set('ComponentMake', ComponentMake)
          .set('EquipModel', EquipModel)
        };
        let obj = {
            'compartid_auto': compartid_auto,
            'progid': progid,
            'componentId': ComponentId,
            'componentDescription': ComponentDescription,
            'componentType': ComponentType,
            'componentMake': ComponentMake,
            'equipModel': EquipModel
        };
        return this._http.post("api/Component/getComponents", obj).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
      }
```

Create a backend model that matches the client request model

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public int Compartid_auto { get; set; }
    public int Progid { get; set; }
    public string ComponentId { get; set; }
    public string ComponentDescription { get; set; }
    public string ComponentType { get; set; }
    public string ComponentMake { get; set; }
    public string EquipModel { get; set; }
}
```

Then use that model in your API and read the data from the request model

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Component_Details>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetComponents([FromBody]RequestModel model)
{
    ...add your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcus. This is very helpful.  I will change my code and get back to you.  :)

Comment: Marcus Höglund , Is my return the Stored Procedure is correct. ??

Comment: @hash, It looks good to me. But, If you are able to POST the model to the backend api then this question is solved. If you have trouble with the stored procedure communication then I suggest you to create a new question which does not include the api stuff. Then it's more likely you get good answers from the stored procedure guys :) if my answer helped, please upvote/accept

Answer (score 0):

How about change `this._http.get()` to `this._http.post()`.

You may also use an interface in your angular that has same properties as of your model in the web api so then you can just use `[FromBody]ModelName` that saved me a lot of work